# Spring WebFlux | Performance Logger In case of Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm working on logging the START, END and time taken by methods which generate Flux or Mono. I have used implementation as below.

This code works fine, but is a problems -

When there is an exception - the Exit and time never gets logged. When debugged, the flow never goes into flatMap() or collectList(). Could you please check and advice if any issues?

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAspect
{

    //AOP expression for which methods shall be intercepted
    @Around("execution(* com.company.service..*(..)))")
    public Object logEndpointPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();

        //Get intercepted method details
        String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

        final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        log.debug("Start: " + className +"."+methodName);
        //Measure method execution time
        stopWatch.start();
        Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

        if(result instanceof Mono){
            return ((Mono)result).flatMap(r -> {
                logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
                return Mono.just(r);
            });
        }
        else if(result instanceof Flux){
            return ((Flux<Object>)result).collectList().flatMapMany(r -> {
                logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
                return Flux.fromIterable(r);
            });
        }
        else{
            logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void logExecutionTime(final String className, final String methodName, final StopWatch stopWatch){
        stopWatch.stop();
        //Log method execution time
        log.debug("Exit: " + className +"."+methodName);
        log.debug("[ " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " mls ] lasted execution of" + className + "." + methodName );
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what your use case is, you could either add the step `.doOnError(e -> logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch))` or replace the `.flatmap(...)` with `.doFinally(...)`. Additional note: You seem to return the same element as the input in the flatmap in both the Mono and Flux case, so maybe `.doOnNext(...)` is more correct for the cases?

Comment: Thank you. I'm writing this at a central place - an advice. doFinally, doOnNext are not working at central place. If I add the code exactly where the Flux is generated (a controller method), then it works. Any idea to make it work in advice?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you replace `flatMap(...)` with `doOnNext(v -> logExecutionTime(className, methodName, stopWatch))`, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be called when `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` doesn't send an error signal. So the combination of `doOnNext(...)` and `doOnError(...)` should assure that `logExecutionTime(...)` is called. The option, `doFinally(...)` is called upon termination of the publisher, so I'd assume it wouldn't fit the use case for your stopwatch.

Comment: It works. I was not subscribing to it after doing doOnNext or doOnError. Thank you for you help.